# Replace text + optional newline in file

Tags: regex, powershell

I've been through other similar questions and tried their advice, but it wouldn't help.
I'm trying to delete a specific line of text in a text file.

My code which works

```
(Get-Content -Path "MyPath.txt" -Raw).Replace('this is the line', '') | Set-Content "MyPath.txt" -Encoding UTF8
```

Now this works but leaves an ugly empty line in the text file. I wanted to also replace an optional newline character by adding this regex at the end of the line

```
\n?
```

and this wouldn't work. The other threads made other recommendations and I've tried all combinations but just can't match. I'm using windows style ending (CRLF)

Both using -Raw and not using it

- \n
- \r\n
- `n
- `r`n

I haven't even added the regex question mark at the end (or non-capturing group in case it needs the \r\n syntax).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `[string]` type's `.Replace()` *method* doesn't support regexes (regular expressions), whereas PowerShell's `-replace` *operator* does.

However, the simplest solution in this case is to take advantage of the fact that the `-ne` operator acts as a *filter* with an array-valued LHS (as other comparison operators do):

```
@(Get-Content -Path MyPath.txt) -ne 'this is the line' |
  Set-Content MyPath.txt -Encoding UTF8
```

Note how `Get-Content` is called *without* `-Raw` in order to return an *array* of lines, from which `-ne` then filters out the line of (non)-interest; `@(...)`, the array-subexpression operator ensures that the output is an array even if the file happens to contain just *one* line.

The assumption is that string `'this is the line'` matches the *whole line* (case-insensitively).
If that is not the case, instead of `-ne` you could use `-notlike` with a wildcard expression or 
`-notmatch` with a regex (e.g.,
`-notmatch 'this is the line'` or `-notlike '*this is the line'`)

Comment: Thank you. The string might not match the entire line (there might be a comment I want to keep) so I've opted for -ireplace 'this is the line(?:\r\n)?', ''.